# Why were there Tony Stark's clothes on-board the Quinjet which ended up on Sakaar?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

When Hulk turned back into Bruce Banner on Sakaar, Thor gave him Tony Stark's clothes. But, what were Tony's clothes doing in Quinjet?

Tony might have helped S.H.I.E.L.D. in the Quinjets' development, but why would he keep his clothes inside it? Even if this particular Quinjet was allotted to The Avengers, it wasn't his personal vehicle like a private jet or limo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It stands to reason that the Quinjet that the Avengers used would have been equipped for the Avengers. In this case, each has a compartment to store some things they might need. In Tony’s case this also means storing some extra clothes.

However, it’s worth noting that the Quinjet was last seen on Earth when the Avengers were saving Sokovia from Ultron. It makes sense it was equipped with equipment for the team even if it wasn’t normally as they had just been using it. Tony being egotistical likely had a spare suit in case his current got damaged so he could still look the part after the battle.

Out of universe though Taika put it in for a joke because of how Tony’s clothes have always looked. Costume designer Mayes Rubeo has the following to say:

> I think it was Taika or [producer] Brad Winderbaum, our creative executive. It just goes into the bible of the '80s, and what would Tony Stark wear? We make his pants tight, and everything is a little tight because it's more fitted for Tony Stark, of course. And we made a joke about it. So you know, it worked.
>
> <sub>[Cinema Blend, How Thor: Ragnarok's Tony Stark Joke Came Together](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/1723939/how-thor-ragnaroks-tony-stark-joke-came-together)</sub>

Taika says the following on the director's commentary track for *Thor: Ragnarok* according to this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/83s4pv/fun_fact_the_reason_of_why_bruce_banner_wear/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf) but I have yet to fact check it.

> **Taika Waititi:** I really wanted to make fun of Tony Stark’s clothes because I think in some of those movies, they seem very funny to me. Some of the funny T-shirt designs and the funky trendy clothes that he always wears.